# Pandas Set value in a group based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set the parent cage value to the value that `has_highest_owner == 'Yes'`
Based on the grouping by the id column.

```
id         has_highest_owner    parent_cage 
834951691                       3TNF2   
834951691                       4D149   
834951691   Yes                 4TMM7
```

In my case I want to set the parent cage of all rows to 4TMM7

```
id         has_highest_owner    parent_cage 
834951691                       4TMM7   
834951691                       4TMM7   
834951691   Yes                 4TMM7
```

Comment: Do all `id`s have a column with `has_highest_owner == 'Yes'`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most efficient and straight-forward solution IMO:

```
df['parent_cage'] = df.fillna('').sort_values(['id','has_highest_owner']).groupby('id')['parent_cage'].transform('last')
```

For sample df:

```
          id has_highest_owner parent_cage
0  834951691                         3TNF2
1  834951691                         4D149
2  834951691               Yes       4TMM7
3  987345927                         83H85
4  987345927               Yes       9283D
5  987345927                         74JSS
```

Yields:

```
          id has_highest_owner parent_cage
0  834951691                         4TMM7
1  834951691                         4TMM7
2  834951691               Yes       4TMM7
3  987345927                         9283D
4  987345927               Yes       9283D
5  987345927                         9283D
```

Comment: This works if the empty cells are actually empty strings, if they are `NaN`, it will do the opposite.  So maybe a `fillna('')` to be safe.  Either way, nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df_filtered = df.loc[df.has_highest_owner=='Yes'][['id','parent_cage']]
df['parent_cage'] = df.merge(df_filtered, on='id').parent_cage_y
df
```

[image]

First filter out the df based on your criteria and then merge back to the original df based on the grouped id!

Answer (score 0):

***Setup*** (showing more than one `id`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'highest': ['', '', 'Yes', '', 'Yes', ''],
    'parent': [123,345,567, 789,256,15]
})
```

Using `mask`:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df.assign(parent=df.mask(df.highest.ne('Yes')).groupby(level=0).parent.ffill().bfill())

   highest  parent
id
1            567.0
1            567.0
1      Yes   567.0
2            256.0
2      Yes   256.0
2            256.0
```